# Replace a querystring in url in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following two urls:

```
url1 = http://localhost:8000/i/dashboard-view?
&level_to_load=1&click_value=%C2%AB%20backll%20Billing%20PartiesC2%
AB%20backll%20Billing%20Parties 

url2 = http://localhost:8000/i/dashboard-view?&level_to_load=1
&click_value=%C2%AB%20backll%20Billing%20PartiesC2%AB%20backll%20Billing%20Parties
&new_value=2
```

I want to be able to pull out the part that contains "click_value=...".

The resulting two urls after the regular expression should then be:

```
url1 = http://localhost:8000/i/dashboard-view?&level_to_load=1

url2 = http://localhost:8000/i/dashboard-view?&level_to_load=1&new_value=2
```

The current regex I have is:

```
url.replace(/click_value=.+&/, '');
```

But it is obviously insufficient. What would be the correct regex here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match the `click_value` GET strings with this regex:

```
&?click_value=[^&#\s]*
```

Therefore, to nix them,

```
result = url.replace(/&?click_value=[^&#\s]*/mg, "");
```

**Discussion**

The key here is matching the right number of characters and no more. I revised my original answer after @ridgerunner's insightful observation that in many urls, though maybe not in yours, there can be an anchor tag at the end, starting with `#`, which we don't want to replace. Thanks to him for the improved answer, which no longer uses lookaheads.

**Token-by-Token**

```
&?                       # '&' (optional (matching the most amount
                         # possible))
click_value=             # 'click_value='
[^&#\s]*                 # any character except: '&', '#', whitespace
                         # (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times
                         # (matching the most amount possible))
```

Comment: Note that the query portion of a URL may be followed by a: `#fragment`. Thus, instead of: `.*?(?=&|$)`, (or better yet: `.*?(?=[&#]|$)` to handle any fragment), I'd just use: `[^&#\s]*` which is shorter, faster and pretty much matches the same thing.

Comment: @ridgerunner Always a treat to read your regex thoughts... Always juicy... Hope you're traveling well. You are right about potential `#` fragments in urls. None in his input so I'll leave it as is, but added a segment pointing to an alternate solution in the comments. All the best. :)

Comment: Wouldn't `/&?click_value=[^&]*/mg` be good enough? If not, why?

Comment: @pawel Because that also matches `&click_value=34 and my brown dog` :)

Comment: @zx81 just like the first example ;) (I was thinking about processing urls one by one). For urls in a blob of text I'd go with `/&?click_value=[^&\s]*/mg` : http://regex101.com/r/yT1pD9

Comment: @pawel Yes, that's good. But ridgerunner's is even better (one more character). It was a nice touch to think of the potential `#` url anchors. :)

Comment: @pawel Between you and ridgerunner, I see that there is a vote for an edit... Putting that in now. :)

Comment: @ridgerunner FYI revised the solution, with proper attribution. :)